# Set the Display Name of a Toast Notification in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm trying out the toast notification features of `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` with a simple Wpf application targeting `net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0` which is necessary for these toasts to work.

Now, the header/title/display name of the toast shows the name of the App project (the assembly name) `WpfApp1` in this case (see picture), and I can't find out how to change it to a proper name without changing the assembly name.

My question is - is it possible to set it?

*NOTE: In WinUI 3 there is a Package.Manifest with a "Display Name" property that affects the text at the top of the toast, but I want to go with a WPF application.*

My toast code looks like this:

```cs
new ToastContentBuilder()
  .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
  .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
  .AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
  .AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
  .AddHeader("1", "LOOK HERE", "")
  .Show();
```

[image]

Comment: Why should it be changeable? It shows which **app** notifies you, same does, for example, Chrome browser, or Windows Update, so you know that browser wants something or update incoming

Comment: @Auditive I don't mind the app title text per se, but I'd like to be able to set the name of the app myself, as possible with WinUI apps.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `AssemblyTitle`, if specified, in the project file is used for the top text of a toast. I have not found any documentation on this though.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  <AssemblyTitle>The text used for the toast</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Aha, didn't know if this property, will try it out. Untill then I'm going with the ` ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Sample toast").Show(toast);` and pure xml, which seems to handle/exclude the title assembly title.

Comment: I think the top text is not given by xml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't change it on toast level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=appsdk#app-notification-structure (in particular "Attribution area").

Comment: Good to know that explanation. I sent a feedback to point out that Attribution area has been added to Windows 10 as well.